# Set up chrome remote desktop in raspbian

Tags: remote, chromium, chrome-os

I would like to know if there is a way to set up chrome remote desktop on my raspberry pi 2. I have installed chromium version 22 and when I try and get the chrome app for remote desktop, it says that I need to install chrome from the google website and I am not able to install the downloaded file. Is there a way to update chromium to be able to download apps from the chrome web store?

Comment: Probably not.  Chrome apps will be compiled for a limited number of platforms not including any model of pi.

Comment: If all you need is to provide support try the web app : https://remotedesktop.google.com/support